# Find the four sides of a rectangle in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to find the four sides of a rectangle with this program, but it works perfectly fine on some images, but fails on others. is there something wrong with my program。

this is my code.I wrote three functions, one is to determine whether the endpoints coincide, one is to calculate the angle between two line segments, and the other is to determine whether the angle is 90 degrees

```
def has_common_point(line1, line2, threshold=5):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = line1[0]
    (x3, y3, x4, y4) = line2[0]

    
    distance_1 = math.sqrt((x1 - x3) ** 2 + (y1 - y3) ** 2)
    distance_2 = math.sqrt((x1 - x4) ** 2 + (y1 - y4) ** 2)
    distance_3 = math.sqrt((x2 - x3) ** 2 + (y2 - y3) ** 2)
    distance_4 = math.sqrt((x2 - x4) ** 2 + (y2 - y4) ** 2)

    
    if (
        distance_1 <= threshold
        or distance_2 <= threshold
        or distance_3 <= threshold
        or distance_4 <= threshold
    ):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def calculate_angle(line1, line2):
    
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = line1[0]
    (x3, y3, x4, y4) = line2[0]

   
    vector1 = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
    vector2 = (x4 - x3, y4 - y3)

    
    length1 = math.sqrt(vector1[0] ** 2 + vector1[1] ** 2)
    length2 = math.sqrt(vector2[0] ** 2 + vector2[1] ** 2)

    
    dot_product = vector1[0] * vector2[0] + vector1[1] * vector2[1]

    
    cos_theta = dot_product / (length1 * length2)
    
    if cos_theta > 1:
        cos_theta = 1
    elif cos_theta < -1:
        cos_theta = -1
    
    theta = math.acos(cos_theta)

   
    angle = math.degrees(theta)

    return angle

def is_angle_close_to_90(line1, line2, threshold=5):
    angle = calculate_angle(line1, line2)
    if abs(angle - 90) <= threshold:
        return True

rectangles = []


processed_lines = set()


for i, line_a in enumerate(lines):
    temp_data_structure=[]
    for j, line_b in enumerate(lines):

      
        if has_common_point(line_a, line_b) and is_angle_close_to_90(line_a, line_b) and (
                tuple(line_b[0]) not in processed_lines):
            
            temp_data_structure.append(line_b)  
           

            processed_lines.add(tuple(line_b[0]))

            if len(temp_data_structure) == 2:
                rectangles.append(temp_data_structure[0])
                rectangles.append(temp_data_structure[1])
                processed_lines.add(tuple(line_a[0]))
                for k, line_d in enumerate(lines):
                    if has_common_point(line_d, temp_data_structure[0]) and   is_angle_close_to_90(line_d, temp_data_structure[0]) and (
                            tuple(line_d[0]) not in processed_lines) and has_common_point(line_d, temp_data_structure[1]) and is_angle_close_to_90(line_d, temp_data_structure[1]) and (
                            tuple(line_d[0]) not in processed_lines):
                        processed_lines.add(tuple(line_d[0]))
                        processed_lines.add(tuple(line_a[0]))
                        rectangles.append(line_d)
                        rectangles.append(line_a)
                    break
```

I want to know why the error occurs and how can I improve my code

Comment: show your input data. [mre]